# Why does render view show black spots and how to fix this?

Tags: faces

I think it may be because of overlapping vertices even though this has never happened before and those upper wing parts don't have these spots. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: By Any chance had you adjusted the  draw distance , since I had similar problems when I increased it ?? If so you could reduce it to 1000 or until it disappears.

Comment: What's a draw distance?

Comment: It means upto what distance from the viewport you can see the models